# Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 takes too long and can't know whats happening

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, dpkg, screen, xterm

I am upgrading my 14.04LTS Ubuntu to 16.04. The problem is that it's been at the same step (Configuring openssl amd64) for like 20 hours. I tried to get to the terminal to know what is happening but the terminal just doesn't open. In Xterm I ran a few commands to resume the installation since Possibly my laptop lost connection and typed in XTerm:

---

### $ sudo apt-get install -f

which displays
Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-fronted), is an other process using it?

Which is understandable for the somewhat frozen upgrading process.

Then I typed:

---

### sudo screen -D -r

But the screen: is not found

Sutting down my laptop is not an option here since I do not want to ducplicate packages. Also, installing a virtual machine to run something remote I am not sure how to do it.

Can this be fixed from the XTerm?

Thanks in advance and looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has been "End of Life" (EOL) for two years. It is not supported anymore. Ubuntu 16.04 will reach EOL by the end of the month. Upgrading from an unsupported version is different and more complicated. You may want to backup your personal data and do a complete new install of Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Check if a dpkg-reconfigure dialog box is open -- the system might be awaiting your input. Also take a look at `top` to see if anything at all is happening. Installation does not begin until after download is complete, so a lost connection should not be an issue. See what /var/log/apt/term.log says the last logged actions were (and when).